# Copy the contents and formatting of a cell if a column within the row = today()

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently building a small project planner in Excel that uses the current date to plot coloured blocks under a date column to depict which stage of the project we are currently at for a particular customer (see image below).

[image: Project planner]

Behind each of the coloured blocks is a drop-down menu populated by a list on another sheet. My aim is to search for the current date in cell A1 ( populated using today() ) within all columns that follow the freezed panes (depicted by the black right hand border). When the current date is found, the value of in each of the coloured blocks should be copied into the corresponding cells so that as the project progresses, a line of coloured blocks are entered for each day (with the relevant text from the drop-down depicting the current stage of that block).

Currently I am using the following formula copied into all cells that follow the freeze:

```
=IF(F$1 = $A$1,$C2,"")
```

However, when the current date is changed this merely moves the copied blocks across to the relevant column without maintaining the old values from previous days.

I've also attempted this with a VLOOKUP so that I can enter it into a macro and run if from a button but the layout does not allow for a successful VLOOKUP.

The simplest solution I believe would be to have a button that allows the user to save the current state of the column with a header that matches the current date however it has been some time since I have coded in VBA and do not remember how to do this.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want some kind of "smart" formula, which refers to a cell containing `TODAY()`, but that after the date changes it still keeps the result? If so, you would probably have to copy and paste-as-values (and that, prior to updating). Please let me know if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much it. The process would be triggered on the click of a button or on closing the workbook.

Comment: Would hidden sheet work for you?

Comment: What has a hidden sheet got to do with it?

Comment: Just a suggestion ... it can be the place holder where you can store previous data and refresh it only when you want it.

Comment: The previous data will be stored in the active sheet though. There can only be one set of records per day so if the process is re-run later in the day the column relating to the current date should be overwritten.

Comment: So till the user presses the button, the data would be previous one. Once button is pressed, the data would be refreshed and you would loose the old data for good. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The aim is that each column corresponds to one day. The dropdowns will be changed once a day you basically get one record a day (each stored in a column)

Comment: In that case you need to store the previous date change as `Boolean` (let say False) in one hidden cell and your code should check if the Boolean value is changed to True or not. The command button which refreshes the data should make this value as True. You can then refresh the data. Sounds ok?

Comment: This shouldn't be done with hidden cells. It should use variables. There is no need to store the previous date as a find can be performed on cell A1 which contains today() meaning it will always have the latest date.

Comment: Can you post a sample workbbok?

Comment: How is the color set in the main block?  By hand each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but here goes...

```
Sub ColorCode()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere")
Set rng = ws.Range("F1:I1")***

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value = ws.Range("A1").Value Then
        ws.Range("C2:C8").Copy
        ws.Range(Cells(2, cel.Column), Cells(8, cel.Column)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ws.Range(Cells(2, cel.Column), Cells(8, cel.Column)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

If you add that to a new module, you can assign it to a command button. I haven't had a chance to test it, but it cycles through the dates in the first row to see if they match the date in A1. If they do, it copies over the values and formats from C2:C8(change if you need to) into the rows underneath that date. You may need to change some of the ranges to suit your specific worksheet.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. Upon runtime I get 'Run-time error "91" - Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited it now. The line where the three asterisks are didn't have a `Set` at the beginning. I got a chance to test it though, and it works now.

Comment: @jezzipin Have you tried it again since I edited? Remember not to copy and paste the asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

So your requirements seem fairly straightforward to me:

1. you need the tracker to identify the column with today's date
2. you need to establish a permanent value for each day as it occurs
3. you need the color of today's values to be added to the cell, and stay that way even after today's date has passed.

The formula you cite in your question, if copied across all cells, will clearly just provide a value on the column for today's date, and unless you use a circular reference to let it self assess and update its value on today's date, it will not retain information when tomorrow comes.

Your idea for a button would work if you want the user to control the time of update, or you could have code that runs either when the workbook opens or when the worksheet itself is activated (placing it in the appropriate object code under either `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` or `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()`.

I think PermaNoob has a right idea of copying the value of the column and pasting the value (rather than the formlula) into that column, but what is missing is appropriate identification of the column containing today's date and the coloring of those cells (if you don't have some method of coloring them that you did not mention). Something like this might work either attached to a button as you suggest, or to the `_Activate` event as I suggest. This is untested but should give you an idea of how to approach it:

```
Sub UpdatePlanner()

    '~~>dim variables and set initial values
        Dim wb As Workbook
            Set wb = Workbooks("NAME or INDEX of YOUR workbook")
        Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets("NAME or INDEX of YOUR sheet")
        Dim rngHeader As Range
            Set rngHeader = ws.Range("F1", ws.Range("F1").End(xlToRight))
        Dim rngDate As Range
        Dim rngColumn As Range
        Dim rngCell As Range

    '~~>loop to find the column with today's date
        For Each rngDate In rngHeader
            If rngDate.value = ws.Range("A1").value Then
                Set rngColumn = ws.Range(rngDate.Address, _
                  ws.Range(rngDate.Address).Offset(65536, 0).End(xlUp)) 'this assumes
                    'your column may not have a value in every row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next rngDate

    '~~>copy and paste the column values and formats
        With rngColumn
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End With

    '~~>loop to add the color formatting (since I don't see this in your formula)
        For Each rngCell In rngColumn
            If rngCell.value = ws.Range(Cells(rngCell.Row, 3)).value Then
                rngCell.Interior.Color = _
                        ws.Range(Cells(rngCell.Row, 3)).Interior.Color
            End If
        Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: I assume you changed `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("NAME or INDEX of YOUR sheet")` so it has the correct worksheet name?  What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Yeah I did. I changed it to Sheet2 as that's what it is called at the moment. The error starts on Line 17 and highlights the whole of the following: Set rngColumn = ws.Range(Cells(rngDate.Row, rngDate.Column), _
                    ws.Range(Cells(65536, rngDate.Column)).End(xlUp)) 'this assumes

Comment: Hi jezzipin. I think I've fixed that `Set rngColumn` statement.  Also: I changed the `Set wb` statement at the top of the variable section to use your workbook's index or name. So for example if your workbook was called Workbook1, you would say `Set wb = Workbooks("Book1")`. Hope this helps.